# Authentication issue in spring-security-core:2.0.0

Tags: grails

I am using spring-security-core:2.0.0 in my Grails application. But even after a successful authentication a page comes with a message 'Sorry, you're not authorized to view this page.' I logged in as ROLE_ADMIN, I want to redirect to two pages according to the roles. For admin role I need to go to admin page and for user role I want to go user page.

Here is my UrlMappings.groovy

```
class UrlMappings {

   static mappings = {
      "/$controller/$action?/$id?"{
         constraints {
            // apply constraints here
         }
      }

   /* get "/"(controller:"book", action:"index")
      get "/books/create"(controller:"book", action:"create")
      post "/books"(controller:"book", action:"save")
      get "/books/$id"(controller:"book", action:"show")
      get "/books/$id/edit"(controller:"book", action:"edit")
      put "/books/$id"(controller:"book", action:"update")
      delete "/books/$id"(controller:"book", action:"delete")
   */

      "/"(view:'auth',controller:'login')
      "/admin"(view:'adminPage')

      "500"(view:'/error')
   }
}
```

LoginController.groovy

```
package com.standout.utilityapplication

import grails.plugin.springsecurity.annotation.Secured

class LoginController {

   def springSecurityService

   @Secured(['ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_USER'])
   def index() {   
      println "INDEX PAGE RENDER FROM MY CONTROLLER";
      def roles = springSecurityService.getPrincipal().getAuthorities()
      println roles;

      if(roles.toString().contains("ROLE_ADMIN"))
      {
         println "admin"
         redirect(uri: "/admin")
      }
      else
      {
         println "not admin"
         redirect(uri: "/dataentry")
      }
   }

   @Secured('ROLE_USER')
   def nonadmin()
   {
      println("===notadmin")
   }

   @Secured('ROLE_ADMIN')
   def admin()
   {
      println("====admin")
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issues are caused by your UrlMapping entries and the security config.

First, try changing the "/"(view:'auth',controller:'login') into

```
"/"(controller:'login')
```

That'll ensure you navigate to your LoginController correclty once you authenticate successfully. The current entry attempts to render an auth.gsp that doesn't have a corresponding action in your LoginController. When only the controller is specified, the index action of that controller is invoked by default.

Second, specify a controllerAnnotation.staticRules value in the Config.groovy file for the other UrlMapping: "/admin"(view:'adminPage')

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
    '/adminPage' : ['ROLE_ADMIN'] ]
```

This ensures the correct authorization is configured for the adminPage static view since /admin resolves to /adminPage based on your UrlMapping.

Refer to the following Spring Security documentation for more details:
http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/v2/guide/requestMappings.html#securedAnnotations